# runnable calls notifyall to wake itself - java

Tags: java, concurrency, runnable, callable

I have a class that implements `Callable` , `X` , and a class that implements `Runnable` , `Y`.

`Y` has a collection of `X`'s , and when one of `X`'s ends I want to wake `Y` , `X` has `Y` as a private field, can I just use `Y.notifyAll()` to wake it?

Comment: you need to synchronize on y in order to call notify on it,

Comment: Sure, if `y` is the thing you have synchronised on, AND if there's nothing else that is waiting, synchronised on `y`.  When you call `notifyAll`, if there are multiple things waiting on the same lock, you have no way of knowing which will wake up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Y` as a private member of `X`, you can call a method in `Y` directly.

`Y.notifyAll()` will notify all threads that already called `wait()`on the same instance of `Y`.